# C++ Error: class/object was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, class, object

Im completely new to C++ and im trying to make a very simple text based combat system, but I keep getting the error: "objPlayer was not declared in this scope".

All the code is written before the main() function:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


    //DECLARE THE UNIT CLASS
    class generalUnit {
    public:
    int health; //the amount of health the unit has
    };


    //DECLARE THE PLAYER THOUGH THE UNIT CLASS 
    void generatePlayer() {
    generalUnit objPlayer;
    int objPlayer.health = 100;
    }


    //DECLARE AND INITIALIZE ALL COMMANDS
    //CHECK STATS
    void comCheckStats() {
        cout << objPlayer.health << endl;
    }
```

Comment: As you can see you’ve declared it only in the `generatePlayer` function. It only exists inside it, nowhere else.

Comment: ah of course. I attempted to remove the function and the error disappeared, however now it says "expected initializer before '.' token. So i put the function back again. Is there a way to make the objPlayer visible to the rest of the code like when using 'public' in a class?

Comment: haha I'll check them out, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to create a variable inside a class pointing to the object of that class you are using. It is already declared and is called `this`.

With operator `->` you can then access member variables from `this`. Like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Player
{
public:
    int health;

    // this is constructor
    Player(int health_at_start)
    {
        this->health = health_at_start;
    }

    void comCheckStats()
    {
        cout << this->health << '\n';
    }
};

int main()
{
    // create player with 100 health
    Player p1(100);
    p1.comCheckStats();

    // create player with 200 health
    Player p2(200);
    p2.comCheckStats();
}
```

As you can see, I am using something called `constructor` to create new instance of Player. It is just function without return type, declared with the same name as the class. It initializes member variable starting data and you can pass some values to it too.

Comment: Thank you so much for the good explanation! :D I believe I have some stuff to study haha